# What is the difference between ?matrix and ?matrix()

Tags: r

I was going through swirl() again as a refresher, and I've noticed that the author of swirl says the command **?matrix** is the correct form to calling for a help screen. But, when I run **?matrix()**, it still works? Is there a difference between having and not having a pair of parenthesis?

Comment: I don't think there's any difference, but I'd have to dig through the source code of `help()` to make sure. The documentation doesn't say anything explicit about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not specific to the swirl environment (about which I was entirely unaware until 5 minutes ago) That is standard for R. The help page for the `?` shortcut says:

> Arguments
>
> topic
> Usually, a name or character string specifying the topic for which help is sought.
>
> Alternatively, a function call to ask for documentation on a corresponding S4 method: see the section on S4 method documentation. The calls pkg::topic and pkg:::topic are treated specially, and look for help on topic in package pkg.

It something like the second option that is being invoked with the command:

```
?matrix()
```

Since `??` is actually a different shortcut one needs to use this code to bring up that page, just as one needs to use quoted strings for help with `for`, `if`, `next` or any of the other reserved words in R:

```
?'?'   # See ?Reserved
```

This is not based on a "fuzzy logic" search in hte help system. Using `help` instead of `?` gets a different response:

```
> help("str()")
No documentation for ‘str()’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??str()’
```

You can see the full code for the `?` function by typing `?` at the command line, but I am just showing how it starts the language level processing of the expressions given to it:

```
`?`
function (e1, e2) 
{
    if (missing(e2)) {
        type <- NULL
        topicExpr <- substitute(e1)
    }
 #further output omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

By running `matrix` and in general `any_function` you get the source code of it.

Comment: yeah, but the question is ?matrix and ?matrix() deliver the same help. True they do. Perhaps the search is based on fuzzy logic and it does not give any error. Swirl sometimes is too tight in semantics and will not allow even a small deviation from standard practice.

Comment: The question was about the R help system, rather than about accessing source code.